# How to wait for all callbacks in a loop before going further in function

Tags: node.js, promise, callback, async-await

I have a Function with takes in user data and in that data i have an **array of emails** to send emails on the given array of emails using node mailer

Now i'm trying to use a foreach loop to iterate through the array and on each iteration i'm using a callback function to check if the given email exist or not

(using a service whoisxmlapi.com) which returns if the email is valid or not 
then if the email is valid then send mail through nodemailer else not

the callback is working fine but the function in which this foreach loop is running goes moves further before callback returns  (i want to wait until all the emails a verified and sent)

```
/* tried[1]  async here */  function sendMails(fields) { 
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 587,
    secure: false,
    requireTLS: true,
    auth: {
        user: email_from,
        pass: password
    }
});
var mailOptions = {
    from: email_from,
    to: _send_to_.toString(),
    subject: fields.email_subject,
    text: fields.msg_type == 'text' ? fields.message_text : '',
    html: fields.msg_type == 'html' ? fields.message_text : ''
};
let __vs_status__ = {
    email: email,
    email_v: false,
    email_s: false
};
_send_to_ = fields.emails
_send_to_.forEach( /* tried[2]  async here */ email => {
    var verifyEmail = /* tried[2] await here */  verifyEmailExist(email, (ev) => {
        console.log(ev.smtpCheck)
        if (ev.smtpCheck == 'true') {

            __vs_status__.email_v = true
            transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) { //want to wait for this too but couldn't test bcz valid email wait was not working properly
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    __vs_status__.email_s = false
                } else {
                    __vs_status__.email_s = true
                }
            });
        }
        // console.log('pushing')
        __email__info.push(__vs_status__)
        //    console.log(__email__info)
    })
});
console.log(/* tried[1]  await here */ __email__info) // this prints before loop and callbacks gets completed (don't want that)
}

// ----------------------------- EMAILS EXIST CHECK CALLBACK ---------------
function verifyEmailExist(email, callback) {
console.log('callback ' + email)
var email = email;
var api_key = apikey;
var api_url = 'https://emailverification.whoisxmlapi.com/api/v1?';
var url = api_url + 'apiKey=' + api_key + '&emailAddress=' + email;
https.get(url, function (response) {
    var str = '';
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        str += chunk;
    });
    response.on('end', function () {
        callback(JSON.parse(str));
    });
}).end();
}
```

i want the foreach loop to complete before moving further and in the for each loop verification of emails and sending status

just not able to get it done

I have tried async/await but didn't work (tried[reference] async / tried[reference] await)

you can test the code by just install required node package and pass a array of email to function sendMails (and to verify emails you would need an api key)

Answer (score 2):

async/await doesn't really matter here because it will essentially wrap/unwrap promises (which you arent using)

I dont really see a problem here. Your `console.log(__email__info)` and your `__email__info.push(__vs_status__)` both need to be within the callback of `transporter.sendMail`

so, the below:

```
_send_to_.forEach( /* tried[2]  async here */ email => {
  verifyEmailExist(email, (ev) => {
    console.log(ev.smtpCheck)
    if (ev.smtpCheck == 'true') {

        __vs_status__.email_v = true
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) { //want to wait for this too but couldn't test bcz valid email wait was not working properly
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
                __vs_status__.email_s = false
            } else {
                __vs_status__.email_s = true
            }
            __email__info.push(__vs_status__)
            console.log(/* tried[1]  await here */ __email__info)
        });
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: i get your point to write email__info.push(__vs_status) into callback 

BUT i wrote this ( console.log(__email__info)) out side because 

against one function call (sendMails) i want to perform other action after foreach is ends 

for example 

against one email i'm sending 10 mails so whether the emails are verified and sent 

i want to save data of these 10 mails against this one (from_email) in one go 

so before saving all data i need all the callback to be finished so i save data at once not on every callback

Comment: asynchronous operations within callbacks will not wait for your console log...they call it "callback hell" because eventually your code will look like stairs. Promises will help with code cleanliness, but handling the asynchronous still needs to occur. so, in psuedo: `populateEmailInfo(/*add code here*/).then(emailInfo=>{/*do what you need*/})`

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use for of loop then for each loop, as for each loop contains callbacks. Here using request-promise module as it returns promise. ANd promisify object of the util library. So that the method which accepts callbacks are converted into promises.

```
const rp = require('request-promise'),
    {promisify} = require('util');

function sendMails(fields) {
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        port: 587,
        secure: false,
        requireTLS: true,
        auth: {
            user: email_from,
            pass: password
        }
    });
    var mailOptions = {
        from: email_from,
        to: _send_to_.toString(),
        subject: fields.email_subject,
        text: fields.msg_type == 'text' ? fields.message_text : '',
        html: fields.msg_type == 'html' ? fields.message_text : ''
    };
    let __vs_status__ = {
        email: email,
        email_v: false,
        email_s: false
    };
    _send_to_ = fields.emails
    for (var email of _send_to_) {
        var ev = await verifyEmailExist(email)
            console.log(ev.smtpCheck)
            if (ev.smtpCheck == 'true') {

                __vs_status__.email_v = true
                const sendMail = promisify(transporter.sendMail).bind(transporter);
                const info = await sendMail(mailOptions);
                if (!info) {
                    console.log("error");
                    __vs_status__.email_s = false
                } else {
                    __vs_status__.email_s = true
                }
            }
            __email__info.push(__vs_status__)
    }
    console.log( /* tried[1]  await here */ __email__info) // this prints before loop and callbacks gets completed (don't want that)
}

// ----------------------------- EMAILS EXIST CHECK CALLBACK ---------------
async function verifyEmailExist(email, callback) {
    console.log('callback ' + email)
    var email = email;
    var api_key = apikey;
    var api_url = 'https://emailverification.whoisxmlapi.com/api/v1?';
    var url = api_url + 'apiKey=' + api_key + '&emailAddress=' + email;
    const str = await rp(url);
    return JSON.parse(str);
}
```

Comment: @Divento Mark it as answer, if it resolves the issue.